# refs/pull/*/head -> origin/pr/* appearing on a git pull

Tags: git, github

Since about a month ago, every time I issue a 'git pull', I end up with a bunch of remotes/origin/pr/* branches on my 'git branch -a', which map directly to the number of pull requests having ever been opened in this repo.  Doing a 'git remote prune origin' cleans them up.

Before Pull :

```
C:\experimental [develop]> git branch -a
* develop
  feature/291
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

Pull :

```
C:\experimental [develop]> git pull
From https://github.com/.../experimental
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/1/head -> origin/pr/1
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/10/head -> origin/pr/10
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/100/head -> origin/pr/100
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/101/head -> origin/pr/101
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/102/head -> origin/pr/102
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/103/head -> origin/pr/103
...
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/103/head -> origin/pr/382
```

After Pull:

```
C:\experimental [develop]> git branch -a
* develop
  feature/291
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/pr/1
  remotes/origin/pr/10
  remotes/origin/pr/100
  remotes/origin/pr/101
  remotes/origin/pr/102
  remotes/origin/pr/103
...
  remotes/origin/pr/382
```

Cleanup :

```
C:\experimental [develop]> git remote prune origin
Pruning origin
URL: https://github.com/.../experimental.git
 * [pruned] origin/pr/1
 * [pruned] origin/pr/10
 * [pruned] origin/pr/100
 * [pruned] origin/pr/101
 * [pruned] origin/pr/102
 * [pruned] origin/pr/103
...
 * [pruned] origin/pr/382
```

After Cleanup :

```
C:\experimental [develop]> git branch -a
* develop
  feature/291
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

How do I stop the initial 'git pull' from pulling them down ?  It only started to happen about a month and a bit ago.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably you followed the suggestion how to check out pull requests locally (see https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally ). To get rid of this, just remove the line

```
fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

from your `.git/config`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I checked my .git/config file and do not have that entry.

    [remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/.../experimental.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

:(

Comment: Or maybe your global `~/.gitconfig` has this entry. Check with `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch`.

Comment: Aha -- thankyou !  Somehow it was added to my system level git config.  *shrug*.

Comment: This suggestion was removed from GitHub's documentation sometime in 2014, but can still be seen in [the Internet Archive's snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20130816145110/https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally) of the page.

Answer (score 1):

> Somehow it was added to my system level git config.

This was probably GitHub for Windows (or Mac?), which provides an enhanced `--system` config, as you discovered, including:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

(You can confirm with `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch`.)

If you don't find the `origin/pr` refs useful, removing the `refs/pull` line will indeed do the trick. Personally I find them useful, so the `prune` behavior you discovered was frustrating:

In older versions of Git, if the `refs/pull` line came after the `refs/heads` line a `remote prune` would strip out the `origin/pr` refs; swapping the lines let the `origin/pr` refs survive.

That bug was fixed in [Git 1.9.2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.9.2.txt):

```
 * "git fetch --prune", when the right-hand-side of multiple fetch
   refspecs overlap (e.g. storing "refs/heads/*" to
   "refs/remotes/origin/*", while storing "refs/frotz/*" to
   "refs/remotes/origin/fr/*"), aggressively thought that lack of
   "refs/heads/fr/otz" on the origin site meant we should remove
   "refs/remotes/origin/fr/otz" from us, without checking their
   "refs/frotz/otz" first.

   Note that such a configuration is inherently unsafe (think what
   should happen when "refs/heads/fr/otz" does appear on the origin
   site), but that is not a reason not to be extra careful.
```